# Unresolved function or method require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webstorm, require

I've got an error 'Unresolved function or method require()' in the WebStorm ES6 development environment.

So I try to Node.js Core library enabled.

[image]

`Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM` under `Coding Assistance` subsection enable option. But after paused in that state (Configuring Node.js Support... dialog), nothing happens when the dialog window is closed.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: it doesn't look like `require()` is in node js's core library, from the list of packages there.

Comment: what WebStorm version do you use? Looks as if it's old and doesn't provide support for Node.js 8+, so library installation fails

Comment: @Katie.Sun 
I added require to node js's core library, but it still does not work.

Comment: @lena
My webstorm version is 2016.2.
Does not this version support Node.js 8+?

Comment: it definitely doesn't. In particular, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26508 is fixed in 2017.1.3

Comment: I have the same issue in webstorm 2022.1.1